# R remove repetitive strings

Tags: r, string, null

I want to remove repetitve strings in R.
I simplified my situation and tried two things.

```
#1 remove a vector
x=c("a","a","b","c","d")
x[-(x=="a")]
```

I expected it would remove all "a"s but the result is

```
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Secondly, I tried "NULL"

```
x[x=="a"]=NULL
```

But there was an error :

```
Error in x[x == "a"] = NULL : replacement   has length zero
```

How can I remove repetitve strings? In this situation, removing all "a"s and print

```
[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

?

Comment: There is a way of coercing "a"s to NA and do na.omit() but I wish there is a better solution

Comment: change your `-` to `!`. We use `!` for `not` in case you want to change from TRUE to FALSE, but if you had integers, then you use `-`.  so in your case, you should do `x[!(x=="a")]` or `x[x!="a"]` which reads as `x such that x is not equal to a`

Comment: @Onyambu - or even `x[ -which(x == "a") ]`

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to remove 'a' as it is repeated, then use `table` to get the frequency of elements and based on that subset the string with `%in%` and negate (`!`)

```
x[!x %in% names(which(table(x) > 1))]
#[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

Or using `duplicated`

```
x[!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))]
```

---

Or if it is based on the adjacent elements that are repeated, use `rle`

```
with(rle(x), values[lengths ==1])
#[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

NOTE: All the above removes the elements programmatically instead of manual checks

---

From the OP's comments, it is clear that they want to remove only specific elements that are known to be duplicates.  In that case,

```
x[! x %in% c("a")]
```

Here, we use `%in%` as `==` can only be used for comparing a single element

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, but I forgot to say that I don't want to remove all the repetitve cases. Actually, the vector is more complex like ("americans","americans","applause","applause","applause","is","is","is"...). I want to erase specific vectors like "is".

Comment: @Damelim In that case just do `x[! x %in% c("is", "applause")]`   I am using `%in%` to check for more than one element `==` works only for a single element

Comment: That's the code I wanted! Thank you so much